# Can the Same FCM token be regenerated after app uninstall and reinstall?

Tags: firebase

After our app uninstalled and then reinstalled our app, sometimes our app get the same token id.

Can the **same** FCM token be issued when reinstalling the app after deleting it?

We use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token` api in our app, and it seems that there are cases where the same token is generated.

I heard that token is created by using the current time stamp. Is this right?
It would be helpful if you could explain the token generation logic.

We want to get a different token.

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever, if you get a new token or the same after reinstallation. Also it's possible, that the token changes from time to time without reinstallation. There is no (documented) logic behind token generation and it really doesn't matter, because you can't do anything about it anyways.

Comment: Why does it even matter if you get a new token or keep the same?

Comment: The cases when the token may be regenerated are enumerated in the documentation, [this blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/04/managing-cloud-messaging-tokens) and previous questions. Outside of that, you should follow the [best practices for managing tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens) from the Firebase documentation. Finally: don't try to parse the FCM token, but treat it as an opaque string that unique identifies an instance of your app on a specific device.